# approach to check Lightning Readiness for Managed Packages

Tags: lightning, managed-package, lightning-experience

What should be the flow of checking whether managed packages are lightning ready?

Comment: Are you asking how to verify If you're app is lighting ready to be in app exchange ?

Comment: No, to check whether an installed package is lightning ready within an org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to look at the app's listing in AppExchange to see if its lightning ready. Below is an example of listing that says its lightning ready.

[image]

Being Lightning Ready means ISV's are committing to customers that their app works as designed in Lightning Experience.It also means they meet the requirements for the Lightning Ready designation as documented in the [ISV Lightning ready guide.](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/30000000bwUm/Y6To9GKaWAJeRlbaUReGYz4FHR.xW6xLcwahCgIO7DI)

Other that couple of other ways are.

1. Talk to the app provider to see if they are providing lightning support for all use cases
2. Install the app in sandboxes and perform a functionality testing in lightning experience.

> **Note:** Keep in mind though Lightning ready doesn't necessarily mean
>   everything is lightning components. It just all the use cases of the
>   app are 100% supported in lightning experience.